# Output nested list to xlsx using Django

Tags: django, nested-lists, openpyxl

I have a complex nested list of models that looks like this:

```
hierarchy_tree =  ['0000', 'hierarchy' [['0000-22', 'hierarchy2', [['0000-33', 'hiearchy3', [['0000-44-4444', 'hiearchy4', [['0000-55-5555-55', 'hiearchy5', []]]]]]]]]]
```

I am able to easily display this in a template using dot notation - example:

```
{% for hierarchy in hierarchy_tree %}
            <tr class="item" data-id="{{system.0}}" data-parent="">
                <td>
                    {{hierarchy.0}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{hierarchy.1.genericname}}
                </td>
```

Now I am trying to output this to an .xlsx file but I cannot figure out how to pass all of the levels of this list? How can I do the same thing that I did in the template to pass this list to excel?

I have tried the following which will return the 1st list but throws an error (ValueError at /post/1/export/hierarchy/ - cannot covert(my passed in list)to excel) for the sublists because of the way that they are nested I believe.

```
for r in hierarchy_tree:
    ws.append(r)
```

I have also tried and failed repeatedly to access the sublists using other methods.

So bottom line I need to figure out how to access and pass the values for the sublists - any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment:** ... is just 1 row in the list ...

Python `print` a instance of Type `list` in **one line**, surounding with **[ ... ]**.
Your `hierarchy_tree` is of Type **list of n lists**.
Every **n't** `list` in `hierarchy_tree` starts with **[** and ends with **]**.

---

You have to break your `hierarchy_tree` into **row Data**.
For instance:

```
def treeWalk(tree, level=0):
    rData = [ '' for i in range(level)]
    for item in tree:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            if len(rData) > level:
                ws.append(rData)
                level += 1

            treeWalk(item, level)
            return
        rData.append(item)

treeWalk(hierarchy_tree)
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***

Comment: Thank you for your response - this was very helpful - learned some stuff

Comment: There is something I am trying to figure out though - the example I gave above is just 1 row in the list "hierarchy_tree =  ['0000', 'hierarchy' [['0000-22', 'hierarchy2', [['0000-33', 'hiearchy3', [['0000-44-4444', 'hiearchy4', [['0000-55-5555-55', 'hiearchy5', []]]]]]]]]]"  -  The loop ignores any additional rows - I am still looking at it  - will let you know -  thanks again for your help

Comment: I figured it out last night - I should have posted here. Thanks a billion :)